# Elixir Phoenix app returning 431 error when headers are longer than ~4000 chars

Tags: http-headers, elixir, phoenix-framework

My Phoenix app has started giving 431 error responses to some page requests when the user's browser has accumulated too many cookies. (Our site is one subdomain of a very large domain, and many cookies are set globally on the top-level domain.) How can I configure my app to allow longer headers to avoid this error?

Answer (score 9):

The Phoenix webserver adapter (by default `Phoenix.Endpoint.Cowboy2Adapter`) allows you to adjust the default max header size etc. For example I ended up using this config:

```
config :my_app, MyAppWeb.Endpoint,
  http: [
    port: System.get_env("PORT") || "80",
    protocol_options: [max_header_value_length: 8192]
  ],
  ...
```

For full options & more description, see:

- https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Endpoint.html#module-adapter-configuration
- https://hexdocs.pm/plug_cowboy/Plug.Cowboy.html
- https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.5/manual/cowboy_http/

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the browser `Cookie`, like:

[image]

Comment: Clearing cookies does not resolve the problem because the cookies will just be re-sent and stored anew next time you make http requests. See description above.